# Kinect v1.8 SDK with Unity3D

Tags: unity-game-engine, kinect

Am developing a football game in Unity3D . in which I need only the foot orientation of the users from which I can detect the angle of the kick.

Am now tracking the whole skeleton data , but I can't able to get the foot orientation angles precisely.

Is there anyway that I can track only the foot of the user without going for the method of Tracking whole skeleton.

Answer (score 2):

I have developed some games with unity and kinect. what I did is, 
I could access the transform.position of each joints represent the skeleton. then by using relative positions of several joints, I detected the body gestures.
Hope this helps
let me know if you need any assistance

Comment: As I said, I need to track the foot only which is to be detected as an Object, not as a skeleton. Because when I am inhibiting the skeleton tracking procedure the kinect has to track the whole body, from which I can't able to get the precise angles of the foot orientations.

Comment: But thanks for answering, but I can do that skeletal tracking FYI. And I have did that too. I need help in somewhat tracking some objects, using kinect.